# Login issue, I need to double click to in order to login, how can i fix that to only click one time

Tags: reactjs

```
 const onSubmit = async (values) => {
             await axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/user/checkLogin',
            data: values,
            withCredentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
          setUser(response.data);
          })
          .then(()=> {
            if(user.length === 0){
                setMessage("Invalid Email or Password")
              }else{
                localStorage.setItem("userInfo",JSON.stringify(user)) 
                history.push("/")
            }
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
          
      
    }
```

//If I type the correct account, The first click it will appear the message Invalid password or email , the second click will then have the account and login successfully

Comment: show as the button code and the validating functions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### The Problem

The problem is with the second `then` block where you are trying to check the `user` object (which was the result of your API call) just after `setUser` method.

##### Solution

```
const onSubmit = (value) => {
  const response = axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/user/checkLogin',
    data: values,
    withCredentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": 'application/json'
    }
  })
    .then(response => JSON.stringify(response.data))
    .then(user => {
      setUser(JSON.stringify(response.data))

      if(user.length === 0) {
        setMessage("Invalid Email or Password")
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo",JSON.stringify(user)) 
        history.push("/")
      }
    })
    .catch(console.log) 
}
```

##### Explanation:

The first `then` method will parse your response data and **return** it.

The second `then`, get the user (the result of parsing `response.data`) and set it on the `user` state. here you can also check the conditions about the `setMessage` or pushing to another route.

##### Optional

You can also use check the `user` response on a `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(user.length === 0) {
    setMessage("Invalid Email or Password")
  } else {
    try{
      localStorage.setItem("userInfo",JSON.stringify(user))
      history.push("/")
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
}, [user]) 

const onSubmit = (value) => {
  const response = axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/user/checkLogin',
    data: values,
    withCredentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": 'application/json'
    }
  })
    .then(response => JSON.stringify(response.data))
    .then(user => {
      setUser(JSON.stringify(response.data))
    })
    .catch(console.log) 
}
```

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem):

> always catch possible exceptions from setItem()

**Note:** With the first implementation if any errors occurred during the `localStorage.setItem`, it catches by the catch block, but in the second implementation you need to wrap this method in a `try/catch`